# Gmail Contacts delete problem - iPad

Tags: ipad, contacts, gmail

iPad Gmail - on Compose TO: line

as soon as i type first letter, iPad Gmail suggests & shows every contact from every gmail i have ever had on my Windows PC;  i have always had auto-save turned off in Gmail on my PC, & none of the suggested contacts that appear on iPad show up in Other Contacts list  - so no way to get rid of them;

additionally i cannot add Google as an account on iPad  settings as suggested in other forums including Apple & Google - cannot get past the insert gmail address page - NEXT button does not function

Comment: Which version of iPadOS? Are you using GMail in the browser (which?) or the GMail app? If you can’t add a gmail-account are you talking about Apple Mail?

Comment: iOS 14.7; Gmail app on ipad, in browser on PC;  only the  iPad Gmail app sees the ghost addresses - they do not appear on PC - - this is not about apple mail - already have gmail integrated into apple mail along with yahoo & icloud

Comment: go to your google contacts. they are auto-populated with all email adresses you have ever used. Delete any account you do not want. then turn off “create contacts from auto-complete” in the setting of gmail.

Comment: to clarify - the ghost contacts do not show up in Google Contacts nor Gmail Contacts - the ONLY appear as suggestions when using Gmail to send new message on iPad; they do not appear in Gmail on any of my PC's nor do they appear in "other contacts" on the iPad Gmail - i have tried removing the Gmail acct & contacts from iPad, but as soon as i reinstall it the d'mned ghost contacts show up again - a-a-a-a-r-r-gh